# Does the presence of a root on a skin cancer aid in identification?

Tags: dermatology, diagnosis, melanoma

For a couple of years I have had what I suspect to be an undiagnosed squamous cell carcinoma on my big toe. If I scratch off the superficial part it looks like there is a root remaining (I can see what looks like the end of a blood vessel) and of course the thing comes back. Does the presence of the "root" tell me anything about the nature of the item? Thanks.

Comment: Go to your doctor, they can remove it and send it to be checked for cancer - it's super easy to do.  Or they may take one look at it and diagnose it as something else.   If it is a wart they can guide you in removing it permanently.  If it's cancer, they can treat it appropriately.

Comment: Just giving the first sentence of DoctorWhom the highlighting it deserves: **Go to your doctor** and get it checked!

Comment: Thanks for your concern, but I'd still like to know the answer. If it is frozen off it will come back because it has a root. S/he'll say I'm cured and then it comes back a year later somewhere else.